# Selecting an object using Linq from an ordered result

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

Pretty simple question but I'm having a rough morning it seems.

I have the following query built out so far, and I'd like to select the first object in the returned result, but not the ID itself, but the underlying User that has that ID.

Does that make sense?

```
//Edited the code for clarity!
                                                            After this OrderBy is run,
                                                            I have collection I want,
                                                        but I need to select the USER 
                                                             no the UserAuctionLance.
var user = db.UserAuctionLances.Where(a => a.AuctionId == id).OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeOfLance).Select??
```

"Order all of the user bids by descending date, and give me the last user who bid on auction number Foo."

Maybe that makes the question clearer. I need to return a User object.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you tried FirstOrDefault?

Comment: @Nivid: FirstOrDefault in this case would return a UserAuctionLance object, not the linked User object I'm aiming for. Thanks for trying though! :)

Comment: how is your model defined? can you do a .FirstOrDefault(u => u.User) I.e. does the UserActionLance have a user object defined as well....

Comment: You need to tell us how to navigate from your UserActionLances entity to your User entity.

Comment: @Major Byte: FirstOrDefault() takes an optional predicate, not projection.  You can put the a => a.AuctionId == id in there, but not a => a.User

Comment: @Major If you just take the predicate out, you may be fine: .FirstOrDefault().User

Comment: @Jim .FirstOrDefault().User has a possible NullReferenceException, you would have to break it up and check for a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
var user = db.UserAuctionLances.Select(a=>a).Where(a => a.AuctionId == id).OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeOfLance).FirstOrDefault();
```

That should return the first result, or null if none exist.

And as you explained below, you want the user object within a userAuctionLances so something more like:

```
var user = db.UserAuctionLances.Where(a => a.AuctionId == id).OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeOfLance).Select(a=>a.UserObject).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: But that returned a UserAuctionLance object, NOT the underlying User object I'm aiming for.

Comment: Is the User object part of the UserAuctionLance object? Then modify the statement above to be: source.Where(...).OrderBy(...).Select(a=>a.UserObject).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Now you understood my question. :) There we go, edit your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: What is the point of .Select(a => a). This can just be eliminated if you are just returning the same thing.

Comment: @Kevek:  OMG I am soo sorry, i edited your question instead of mine!  My bad totally!  Undid my edits.  Again my apologies.

Comment: @Jim there's really no point, it was just to keep the same methods as initially posted. a little naive on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try ..

```
var user = db.UserAuctionLances.Where(a => a.AuctionId == id).OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeOfLance).Select(s => s.User).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var user = db.UserAuctionLances.Where(a => a.AuctionId == id).OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeOfLance).Select(s => s.User).LastOrDefault();
```

Hard to tell, cause i hardly know what ur data structure is like.

Comment: @scartag Thats what Because whats the relation between the UserAuctionLances and User table.

Comment: But that returned a UserAuctionLance object, NOT the underlying User object I'm aiming for.

Comment: If you are using EF4 and the user table is linked to the UserAuctionLance table via a relationship, the User entity should be a navigation property ... hard to tell though.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia .. i think you should try it out.

Comment: @scartag: if FirstOrDefault() returns null, calling .User on it will crash with NullReferenceException.  Should select before call to First/Last.

Comment: @James Micheal Hare ... very true .. i guess i should modify this or just delete .. a better answer exists.

Comment: @scartag: just modify it, still a valid answer, you deserve an uptick for it if it's modified.

Answer (score 1):

```
var user = db.UserAuctionLances.Where(a => a.AuctionId == id).OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeOfLance).Select(a => a.User).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will sort the matches and then return the first item that matches or `null` if it's a reference type (class) if not found.